# LINQ: get 'Use the new keyword to create an object instance' when more than one records are returned

Tags: .net, linq

...new to LINQ and could do with some help.

I'm querying some remote xml and using LINQ to put the results into a List. When the xml query only returns 1 record all is fine and i get a fully populated 'GetMPResult' object by accessing [0] item in the list.

...but, if there is more than 1 record returned in the xml, i get  'Use the new keyword to create an object instance'

any ideas?

```
XDocument myData = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
        List<GetMPResult> mp = (from mpItem in myData.Descendants("twfy")
              select new GetMPResult
            { 
                Member_id = mpItem.Element("member_id").Value,
                House = mpItem.Element("house").Value,
                First_name = mpItem.Element("first_name").Value,
                Last_name = mpItem.Element("last_name").Value,
                Constituency = mpItem.Element("constituency").Value,
                Party = mpItem.Element("party").Value,
                Entered_house = mpItem.Element("entered_house").Value,
                Entered_reason = mpItem.Element("entered_reason").Value,
                Left_house = mpItem.Element("left_house").Value,
                Left_reason = mpItem.Element("left_reason").Value,
                Person_id = mpItem.Element("person_id").Value,
                Title = mpItem.Element("title").Value,
                Lastupdate = mpItem.Element("lastupdate").Value,
                Full_name = mpItem.Element("full_name").Value,
                Url = mpItem.Element("url").Value,
                Image = mpItem.Element("image").Value,
                Image_height = mpItem.Element("image_height").Value,
                Image_width = mpItem.Element("image_width").Value,
            }).ToList<GetMPResult>();
        GetMPCompleteEvent(mp[0]);
```

Comment: what's the signature of GetMPCompleteEvent() method ?

Comment: ..its erroring on the select so not getting that far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't look like it has to do with the number of objects, since it's the error message from `NullReferenceException`.

I think that there's simply some element among those you are processing that does not exist even though you are expecting it, so you get the null reference.

Try commenting out *all* the property setters in the initialization list (`select new GetMPResult`) -- if it doesn't throw, it means you found the problem.

Comment: just tried commenting them out...if i comment them all out i get no error/no data. If i uncomment any of the items (remembering to remove the comma from the end) i get the error again.

Comment: @AlanBeech: Then you should go looking for an empty `<twfy></twfy>` in your XML.

Comment: ah...got it. The XML has an extra level  '<match></match>' around each of the records when multiple are returned.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction...it's appreciated.